# Disk cache vs Recreating the image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching, core-graphics

I currently have an app where I do a lot of image manipulation. I basically take an image that is 320x320 (*or 640x640 on Retina*) and scale it down to 128x128 (*or 256x256 on Retina*) before rounding off its corners and applying a glossy highlight. Everything is done using Core Graphics drawing.

At any one time there could be around 600 images that need this processing so I do around 40 on app launch using a background thread and cache them into a FIFO queue. When an image not in the cache needs processing, I do so and add it to the end of the cache, discarding the first cached image. If that first image is needed again it goes through the same process.

What I would like to know is if it would make more sense, and is ultimately more efficient, to save the discarded images to disk rather than recreate them from scratch the next time they are needed, as I could instead just read them from disk.

These images are also displayed using a `CALayer` and therefore there may be a overhead when the layers' contents are set because of the conversion from `UIImage` to `CGImage`. If I store them on disk I believe they can be read directly as a `CGImage`?

Any ideas and input on improving the efficiency of this process will be sincerely welcomed.

Comment: Note that decompressing an image takes longer than reading it from the disk http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/10/avoiding-image-decompression-sickness/ I guess you'll have to time each part (reading,decompressing,scaling+rounding+glossy) and see what happens.

Comment: I would scale+round+gloss before saving, so the only thing I'd need to understand is the decompressing cost. Can images not be stored uncompressed? Such as just storing their data for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal choice would be to use a disk cache.

However, you say 'which is more efficient' - what do you mean?

- If you mean faster then the disk cache is probably going to win.
- If you mean more space efficient then recreating them will win.
- If you mean lower memory usage then it entirely depends on your implementation!

You will have to try it and see :)

However, the advantage of the disk solution is that the second time your app starts up, it will already have done the processing so will start faster. That's why I'd use the disk.

Comment: By efficient, I meant faster. I only ever hold around 40 images in memory at any one time so memory use isn't really an issue. The images are subject to change as they are the artwork from the users iPod music library so they would need to be cached to disk after every sync. Do you think it would be quicker to read from disk using  something like `CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider` and setting the layer contents to the result rather than using `UIImage` and it's convenience methods?

Comment: I think UIImage will have been written with as little overhead as possible (it might even use the CALayer stuff behind the scenes!) Personally I would go with the convenience of UIImage (unless it starts to be a problem. Then you should do some benchmarking to see which is faster and if the more complicated code is worth it). How frequent does the artwork in the music library actually change? I bet it's not that often - if it's speed you're after then definitely use the disk.

Comment: It's not specifically the artwork that changes. Each `MPMediaItem` has an id that's only persistent between iPod library syncs (*where there's a change, such as adding or deleting albums*). The only way you could relate a cached cover on disk to an album is to use that id so each time it syncs and an items id changes you'd need to re-cache the entire library.

Comment: Bugger, that's annoying :( You could use a non ID key for the cached images? Or failing that you have no choice; clear the cache and recreate the images on demand on a background thread. Though I'd assume that the number of times the app runs should be higher than the number of syncs which clear the ID so you'll still get a performance benefit.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, saving and then reading from the disk is faster. I had some memory warnings by doing it over and over, instead of saving and reading. But, the only to know for sure is to try. I was using around 1000 images, so it makes senses in my case to use the disk.

Comment: In development I've only had to deal with a max of around 600 images but this is liable to increase once the app is released. I only ever hold around 40 images in memory which takes around 10-12mb on an iPhone 4 and around 2.5mb on 3GS.

Comment: Try to hold as much as possible, for instance, even if it doesn't make sense in your context, always to try to push things ( Murphy Law... :P ). So if you need a max of 600 at the moment try to hold 800, just to see how your app behaves. Check the log for memory warnings.

Comment: On Retina the images are an average of 250k (256x256x4) so to hold 600 in memory would take around 150mb which just isn't possible on an iPhone. This is why I keep it around the 10mb mark or lower.

Comment: 150 mb in the ram... Don't forget that... At the mark of 90 mbs my app was receiving memory warnings and was shutting down. Test it using Activity Monitor from the Instruments.

Comment: I'm sorry but I seem to be missing your point. If your app was being shut down around 90mb how can I expect to hold 150mb + in memory?

Comment: I was holding an array with UIImages. Big images and thumbnail images. That been said, they were on RAM. What I am doing now is: the same array without the big images and an NSString instead. There I have the path for my big images that are stored in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

It's also good to give a try github's libs that downloads and caches UIImage/NSData from Internet.

It may by SDWebImage(https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) or APSmartStorage (https://github.com/Alterplay/APSmartStorage).

APSmartStorage helps to get data from network and automatically caches data on disk or in memory in a smart configurable way. Should be good enough.